# Libreoffice Calc - replace text 123db with number -123

Tags: libreoffice-calc, find-replace, cell-formatting

I have a column imported from something else where money values are expressed as `123.00DB`

I need to convert them to something more useful, which needs to be numeric, eg `-123.00`

I want to do this with a cell formula rather than GUI point and click.

There are two steps... convert the trailing DB to leading -, then make the cell numeric.

Is this possible?

Comment: Something like: `=--LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)` maybe?

Comment: Unfortunately that only gets rid of the DB - doesn't make it negative

Comment: Remove one of the `-` from the formula